# Prevent form fields from repopulating after clicking the back button

Tags: php, html, browser-cache

I have a form. After it is successfully submitted, there is a server side redirect to view the new entry.

**Problem**: All the inputs are still populated with the last values after the back button is pressed (it doesn't resubmit the form automatically or show that "confirm form submission" prompt). This allows the user to manually click "Submit" again and submit a duplicate entry very easily, which is what I want to avoid. Note that this is not the classic "repost" problem, we are using the post/redirect/get pattern.

There are 20+ fields in the form, and technically speaking it's *possible* that two identical entries could be legitimate, but I just want the fields to be cleared when the user presses the back button.

Here's what I've tried:

**No-cache headers**

```
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-store, no-cache, private, max-age=0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
```

**Combinations of No-cache meta tags**

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

**Submitting and redirecting with javascript**

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
        window.location = response.redirectUrl;
    });
});
```

**"Refresh" redirect after submitting the form**

```
header('refresh:0; url=view_entry');
```

**Refresh triggered by session data** (getting a little hacky here...)

```
// psuedo PHP code for the "add" page
if ($_SESSION['submit']) {
    $_SESSION['submit'] = 0;
    redirect(current_url); // Cross fingers and hope this clears the form
}
if ($formValid and $saveEntry) {
    $_SESSION['submit'] = 1;
    redirect(next_url);
}
```

None of this works, the fields are still populated after hitting the back button. The last option actually triggers the "confirm form submission" prompt, which isn't what I want but at least it's a little better.

I should mention that this is in Google Chrome. Codeigniter and jQuery are available if that helps. I just want the form fields cleared after the user hits the back button, after a successful entry is posted. I don't actually recall having this issue before, and I'm all out of ideas. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: FWIW I've tried enabling Codeigniter's CSRF protection, but the nonce gets regenerated on back button somehow, so it doesn't help...

Comment: How in tarnation instant cereal does the browser regenerate a CSRF token but not clear form values?!

Comment: Or *why* does the browser maintain the field values at all after a post/redirect?

Answer (score 2):

A fast and easy approach would be to clear the fields individually after the response and prior to the redirect.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
        // HERE, clear the fields like...
        $("#field_id_1").val('');
        $("#field_id_2").val('');
        // THEN do the redirect
        window.location = response.redirectUrl;
    });
});
```

it may not be the most comprehensive solution but since you are doing your submission using an ajax call anyway, there is no reason not to do it this way.

Comment: I just read that the form has 20+ entries.  It may be desirable to use something like `getElementsByName` or something similar then loop through them instead of emptying them individually.  Same methodology though.

Comment: I was hoping for a more solid solution but I'll try this. Submitting via ajax was already a bit of a hack.

Comment: Actually this works, so you have my upvote, but I'm not sure I want to use this solution.

Comment: I actually do almost all of my submissions via ajax these days.  No real reason not to.  You can do client-side and server-side validation prior to the user ever leaving site of the form.  Then you can of course change the form elements to aid them in correcting any errors and let them try again.  I dont typically redirect, I would usually show a submission message in the `div` that contained the form (replacing the form).  No reason not to redirect tho I suppose.